# Как грамотнее объявить структуру? Си

Tags: c, массивы, функции, структуры

### Есть задание:

Подготовить данные об абитуриентах, поступающих в университет. Информация о каждом студенте содержит следующие данные:

- Фамилия, имя, отчество;
- Домашний адрес;
- Год рождения;
- Пол;
- Год окончания школы;
- Оценки в аттестате;
- Оценки вступительных экзаменов.

Составить программу, выдающую следующую информацию:

- Список абитуриентов, имеющих в аттестате только оценки 5 и 4;
- Список абитуриентов, имеющих средний балл выше 4.5;
- Количество абитуриентов мужского и женского пола.

Как лучше всего объявить структуру и его объекты (конкретно, какие типы переменных лучше всего использовать, дабы было проще их обрабатывать в main'e)?

Answer (score 3):

А у вас есть выбор?

Фамилия и т.п. - `char[]` или `char*`, годы - `int`, пол - тоже (подумал было о булевом типе, но по нынешним временам уже мало...), все списки - либо действительно списки, либо - что проще - массивы с полем размера.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*